# Why does this Java regex cause "illegal escape character" errors?

Tags: java, regex

I'm working on a [solution to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378978/using-the-netbeans-gui-editor-how-can-i-create-a-jtextfield-or-jformattedtext-fi), as best as I can, using regular expressions. My pattern is

```
"\d{4}\w{3}(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([01][0-9]|2[0-3])([0-5][0-9]){2}"
```

According to NetBeans, I have two illegal escape characters. I'm guessing it has to do with the \d and \w, but those are both valid in Java. Perhaps my syntax for a Java regular expression is off...

The entire line of code that is involved is:

```
userTimestampField = new FormattedTextField(
  new RegexFormatter(
    "\d{4}\w{3}(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([01][0-9]|2[0-3])([0-5][0-9]){2}"
));
```

Comment: The pattern is definitly legal for java, it works in eclipse. Sorry im not with NetBeans.

Comment: Interesting. I'm adding the entire line of code to my question and I'll try to build, even with the error...let's see what happens.

Comment: You use it in string, think of escaping \d and \w with \\d and \\w

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Assuming this regex is inside a Java `String` literal, you need to escape the backslashes for your `\d` and `\w` tags:

```
"\\d{4}\\w{3}(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([01][0-9]|2[0-3])([0-5][0-9]){2}"
```

This gets more, well, *bonkers* frankly, when you want to match backslashes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\\\\\\"); //ERM, YEP: 8 OF THEM
    String s = "\\\\";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(m.matches());
}

\\ //JUST TO MATCH TWO SLASHES :(
true
```

Answer (score 15):

Did you try `"\\d"` and `"\\w"`?

-edit-
Lol I posted the right answer and get down voted and then I notice that stackoverflow escapes backslashes so my answer appeared wrong :)

Comment: The way I see it, you got downvoted for not making effective use of SO's code-formatting capability. ;)

Answer (score 8):

What about the following: `\\d{4}\\w{3}(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([01][0-9]|2[0-3])([0-5][0-9]){2}`

Comment: This gets rid of the error...let's see if it actually works as a regex.

Comment: It appears to be working. +1. However, I accepted butterchicken's answer because it's more in-depth. Thanks for your help, though.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this?

```
\\d{4}\\w{3}(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([01][0-9]|2[0-3])([0-5][0-9]){2}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar because I was trying to escape characters such as -,*$ which are special characters in regular expressions but not in java.

Basically, I was developing a regular expression https://regex101.com/ and copy pasting it to java.

I finally realized that because java takes regex as string literals, the only characters that should be escaped are the special characters in java ie. \ and "

So in this case \\d should work.
However, anyone having a similar problem like me in the future, only escaped double quotes and backslashes.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32714436)

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is to put

```
 *\
 ex: string ex = 'this is the character: *\\s';
```

before your invalid character and not 8 \ !!!!!

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to add the two escaped shortcuts into character classes.  Try this:  `"[\d]{4}[\w]{3}(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([01][0-9]|2[0-3])([0-5][0-9]){2}"`

--Good Luck.

Comment: @MystikSpiral: `\d` and `\w` **are** character classes.  They're *shorthands* (not "shortcuts") for the predefined character classes `[0-9]` and `[A-Za-z0-9_]` respectively.  The brackets are redundant unless you're using them in combinations, like `[\d\s]` or `[\w,.!?]`.