# java regex illegal escape character error not occurring from command line arguments

Tags: java, regex

This simple regex program

```
import java.util.regex.*;
class Regex {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println(args[0]); // #1
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(args[0]); // #2
        Matcher m = p.matcher(args[1]);
        boolean b = false;
        while(b = m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.start()+" "+m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

invoked by `java regex "\d" "sfdd1"` compiles and runs fine.

But if #1 is replaced by `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\d");`, it gives compiler error saying illegal escape character. In #1 I also tried printing the pattern specified in the command line arguments. It prints `\d`, which means it is just getting replaced by `\d` in #2.

So then why won't it throw any exception? At the end it's string argument that `Pattern.compile()` is taking, doesn't it detect illegal escape character then? Can someone please explain why is this behaviour?

Comment: try this `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d");`

Comment: I know it works, that's not what my question is about

Comment: Representing `\d` in Java code has to be done with `\\d` the \ character is treated as an escape character in Java code. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379191/why-does-this-java-regex-cause-illegal-escape-character-errors?rq=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A backslash character in a *string literal* needs to be escaped (preceded by a backslash). When passed in from the command line the string is not a string literal. The compiler complains because `"\d"` is not a valid escape sequence (see  [Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) ).

Comment: so jvm automatically converts `\d` into a `\\d` ?

Comment: and even if on command line it's not a string literal. the SOP shows it as `\d` so it must be getting replaced as it is. When does that conversion happen?

Comment: @Shades88, it will just create a `String` containing `"\d"` the same as `new String("\\d")` would. You don't to escape it on the command line, only within a string literal.

Comment: @Shades88 It's more appropriate to say that `\\d` gets properly converted to `\d` when it's _actually_ passed to `Pattern.compile` (as opposed to the other way around)

Answer (score 1):

The `\` character is used as an escape character for both Java string literals and regular expressions. This confuses many programmers. When you want to create a String in Java to represent a regular expression that has an escape character then you need to escape the Java escape character.

When passing the string in on the command line the JVM handles this for you and simply creates the String.

What you want is this

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d");
```

Comment: even if on command line it's not a string literal. the SOP shows it as `\d` so it must be getting replaced as it is. Also compile method accepts a string, so it's as good as `Pattern.compile("\d")`. When does `\d` to `\\d` conversion happen?

Comment: I don't think it converts it from \d to \\d rather in the Java code the \\d represents the character sequence \d.

Answer (score 1):

The backslash `\` in Java results in an escape in strings. For example, the string `"\t"` results in a tab character in java. This is also why `"\n"` produces a newline.

In regular expressions, `\d` is an escape *with respect to the regular expression, **not** Java*. This means in order to get `\d` in a string literal, you have to type `"\\d"` in the string. Basically, you have to escape the `\` to get the literal value `\d`, and then when `Pattern` compiles the regex, it further escapes the `\d` to be parsed as a digit.

This can be confusing, but long story short, you should never have a single `\` in a string literal for a regular expression since even the string literal `"\\n"` gets parsed properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I understand the question, but it seems like your problem is that you're treating "\d" as a Java escape character, which doesn't exist. To treat it as a regex escape character, use "\d" to escape the Java escape.