# Using Regex for splitting a string in java

Tags: java, regex, split

I want to split a string in java with white spaces. I know that the below line of code does it.

```
String s[] = str.split("\\\s+");
```

Here split function takes the regex by which the string must be split. So when I want to split string `str` through one or more spaces, I should pass `\s+` as regex, then why is `\\\s+` used?

Comment: Triple backslash doesn't compile in java. The proper regex is `\\s+` in java, as 1 backslash is needed to escape the second

Comment: You need to use double backslash. Backslash is a special symbol in Java and you have to use escape character. For backslash escape character is double backslash

Answer (score 1):

This will do the split

```
String s[] = n.split("\\s+");
```

You don't need a third slash'\' - you get Compile Error.
And first '\' is for escaping the second '\'. Used as an escape character for '\s'.

Answer (score 1):

Like Ismail said, you don't need the third backslash.
In your regex you want to use `\s` so in Java you also need to escape your backslashes for your tags.

**Solution:**
[Why does this Java regex cause "illegal escape character" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379191/why-does-this-java-regex-cause-illegal-escape-character-errors)